# Navigation Bar -> How to highlight one particular link even though it is not the current link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a navigation bar and I am using `jQuery` right now to highlight current link on the `nav` bar. But I want to have one page that is NOT on the current link in the `nav` bar, but to have one of the `nav` link highlighted. I cannot figure it out how. Thank you!

This is my current jquery code to highlight current link:

```
$(function () {
    $('a').each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
            $(this).addClass('current');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Add the `.current` class to that link, manually?

Comment: i guess by "manually" mr @Drown above here means do it in html. i guess you don't have access to it or it's auto-gengerated, hence your question? you will need a way to uniquely identify this link, google jQuery Selectors for options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add class to that li .highlight and where is your css written for current class add highlight class also like this

```
.current{
    //your css
}
```

M supposing above is your css for current class so add this in your css

```
.current,.highlight{
    //your css
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't work... I apologize I am not asking it clearly. But Let's say I am at a Download Section, but it not in any of the navigation bar, so none of the navigation link are hilighted. But I want the "Service-Section" to be highlighted.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#home" class="page-scroll">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services-section" class="page-scroll">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#works-section" class="page-scroll">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about-section" class="page-scroll">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team-section" class="page-scroll">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#testimonials-section" class="page-scroll">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact-section" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```